# What is the big O of counting elements in a B tree

Tags: algorithm, graph, tree, big-o, b-tree

For example if I have a tree which nodes have a structure:

```
{ type: 'document' } or {type: 'note'}
```

If I wanted a count of all nodes that have type note what would be count big O for a B tree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Traversal of a B-tree can be done in **linear time** - i.e. `O(n)`.
This is because each of the n nodes should be visted once.

You will spend a **constant time** in each node (checking the type of the node and incrementing a counter, doesn't depend on the size of the tree) - that's `O(1)`.

Therefore the **overall complexity** should be still **linear** - `O(n)`.